# Can't file taxes probably due to ITIN -> SSN change

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, state-income-tax, electronic-filing

I get the following error while filing `married filing jointly` taxes in California via TaxAct (electronically, paperless):

> Rule Number: F540/NR/NRS/2EZ-230 Rule Number Description: There is an
>   error with the Prior Year California Adjusted Gross Income amount
>   provided. The Spouse/RDP on this return is ineligible to participate
>   in the Self-Select PIN program. FTB's records indicate the Spouse/RDP
>   did not file a prior year individual income tax return and does not
>   have a shared secret amount. You can still e-file by signing Form
>   8453-OL. During the Filing Step, you will need to select the Signature
>   Option instead of the Paperless Option. Before you submit your return
>   again, you will be asked to print Form 8453-OL. Sign this form and
>   keep it with your records for at least 4 years.

Some additional information:

- successfully filed Federal/State taxes last year when I had H1B, spouse ITIN
- both received green cards this year and therefore spouse got SSN, so now spouse uses it
- first attempt to file both federal/state tax (when I used the AGI from the previous tax return + Electronic Filing PIN) failed due to `information entered in the 'Filing' step for the secondary taxpayer (second person listed on return) does not match the IRS database: Prior year Adjusted Gross Income (AGI) or prior year PIN`. As per various suggestions, I found that in this case I need to enter 0 in AGI for the spouse.
- this helped with Federal tax (accepted) but still fails for state tax (get the abovementioned error)

---

If I understood correctly, I [should](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/additional-itin-information)

> notify the IRS so we can combine all of your tax records under one
>   identification number. You can visit a local IRS office or write a
>   letter explaining that you have now been assigned a SSN and want your
>   tax records combined.  Include your complete name, mailing address,
>   and ITIN along with a copy of your social security card and a copy of
>   the CP 565, Notice of ITIN Assignment, if available.  The IRS will
>   void the ITIN and associate all prior tax information filed under the
>   ITIN with the SSN.

As the time is very limited, the only option I have is to come to IRS office on Monday, void ITIN and change to SSN and file only state tax in person.

---

Of course I would rather do this electronically or at least file the taxes now and do the change later. Is the solution I mentioned my only option or have I misunderstood something?

P.S. sorry for throw-away account. Long time user, but do not want to show semi-personal information.

Comment: Doubt the IRS fix would go through quickly enough to allow CA return to e-file properly. I'd just paper file and sort out the SSN/ITIN confusion later.

Comment: You can use CalFile at FTB site, instead of TaxAct. It does not ask for the last year's AGI. Notifying IRS is not a bad idea, but I don't think it affects filing state taxes.

Comment: @void_ptr CalFile at FTB is https://www.ftb.ca.gov/online/calfile/index.asp ?

Comment: @failed_taxpayer Yes, that's it. Worked for me.